# Best Text for "Select All"/"Unselect All" Buttons with CheckLists

Tags: terminology, checkboxes, labels

What would "better" text for buttons that select all items in a checklist:

- "Check All" / "Uncheck All"

  "Select All" / "Unselect All"

  or perhaps other text

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might be one of those things that we can over think to death. In the end, might be best to pick one, get it out there, and just test it.

FWIW, I like something akin to this:

```
[ ] item
[ ] item
[ ] item
--------
[ ] select all
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer DA.  

> This might be one of those things that we can over think to death.
Yeah, I know.

Answer (score 7):

I have designed dozens of interfaces with 'select all' and seen the interfaces pass with flying colors in usability tests.

Your example is fine.

Answer (score 4):

I really love the path that Gmail takes.

This way you avoid the verb (select, check, mark, etc.) and goes straight to the checkbox concept itself (all, none, etc.).

And, of course, repeat that structure at the top of the list.

[Gmail checkbox http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/117/gmaile.png](http://img337.imageshack.us/img337/117/gmaile.png)

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not applicable in my scenario. Thanks anyway.